# Can I make a form and save it like an application to add to a fleet of trucks?

Tags: ms-access, database-design

Right now we have paper forms that we fill out for our dispatch trucks. There is quite a bit of information that needs to be filled out and I think it would be easier if my fleet drivers could just pull up an app, fill in the form electronically, then it would send that information back to my home office. Is this possible? If so, can you possibly point me in the direction to get this going? I have Access knowledge, I just don't know if this is capable for distribution on devices if we are not on a shared network.

I haven't tried anything as of right now, I'm just trying to figure out how to get started. I already have Office 365 but my trucks do not.

Expected result would be to pull up the app, fill in the form, then click submit. On the submit click, the form data would be sent to the SQL database of our home office computer.

Comment: Remote distribution and interaction is common topic in many forums. Your question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, you can no more gather a first aid course, or how to change the transmission on your car then you can ask such a broad sweeping question and expect a simple answer in a forum such as this.

Keep in mind that access does not have a viable web development option, and there is no version of Access for Android, or for tablet computers. So, given that you want web forms, or some type of system to be used from smartphones, then Access is the wrong tool and choice here. It is a windows desktop development system, not for tablets, not for Mac, and not for Android.

As such, Access is likely the wrong tool for this type of job.